# Expresiones regulares, obtener el nombre del paquete

Tags: java, regex

He preguntado antes, pero no encuentro la pregunta, si está duplicada, perdona y borren una de las dos. Gracias.

Necesito hacer un patrón que me devuelva el nombre del paquete de código java. Es para una actividad de clase.

El ejercicio pide que dada una cadena con código java, encontremos y devolvamos el nombre del paquete.

Me está resultando bastante difícil esto de las expresiones regulares, así que cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Que haz intentado? adjunta tu código.

Comment: No he intentado nada, aparte de pensarlo, porque no tengo ni idea... Sé que es de cara duras venir a pedir ayuda sin haber mostrado apenas un intento, pero no tengo mucha idea de Regex, así que espero que me puedan echar un cable para hacer el primer ejercicio y de ahí a ver si consigo remontar cabeza y hacer los siguientes.

Perdonen las molestias y gracias.

Comment: https://youtu.be/TPFVgyRCivQ

Comment: La verdad es si googleas rexeg tutorial, vas a encontrar montones de fuentes por donde arrancar. Y podés usar este sitio para practicar: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Por favor no dupliques preguntas y se paciente mientras alguien. Te apoya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package\\s([a-zA-Z]\\w*)(\\.[a-zA-Z]\\w*)*;"\
```

Incluye que empiece por "package", seguido de un espacio, que no empiece por un número, y finalice en punto y coma.